# Asp.net MVC 2 CascadingDropDown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Hi, this is my Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
      makelist = new SelectList(db.CountryMasters.ToList(), "CountryID", "CountryName",1);
        ViewData["CounrtyMaster"] = makelist;

        var modelList = new CascadingSelectList(clientMasterManagement.GetState(makelist.SelectedValue.ToString()), "StateID", "StateName");
        ViewData["StateMaster"] = modelList;

        return View("Create");
}
```

and this is my View Code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.DropDownList("CountryID", ViewData["CounrtyMaster"] as SelectList)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID) %>
</div>

<%= Html.CascadingDropDownList("StateMaster","CountryMaster")%>
```

when I select upper list it's not affecting the second one, can anyone help me here???

Answer (score 0):

User `CascadingSelectList` function instead of `SelectList` in your controller action

```
var makelist = new SelectList(db.CountryMasters.ToList(), "CountryID", "CountryName",1); ViewData["CounrtyMaster"] = makelist;
var modelList = new CascadingSelectList(clientMasterManagement.GetState(makelist.SelectedValue.ToString()), "StateID", "StateName");
ViewData["StateMaster"] = modelList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Html.CascadingDropDownList is not a standard MVC helper. I take it that you are using [Stephen Walther's helper](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx). If so this question will help you out:

[ASP.NET MVC - Cascading Drop Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705540/asp-net-mvc-cascading-drop-down)

Comment: I've use the same code given in Stephen Walther's helper but when I select an item from first listbox it doesn't affect another