# Passing Object From Controller to JavaScript JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is driving me crazy. All I'm trying to do is to pass in a Id to a ActionMethod which is working and have an Object be returned to the javascript. Then in javascript, I want to be able to say something like..Objec.Property, ie/ Student.Name, or Student.GPA.

Any help is appreciated. I tried json but couldn't get that to work either.

ActionResult:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public Epic GetEpicPropertyDetails(int id)
{  
   var Epictemplist = epicRepository.Select().Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
   return Epictemplist.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".ListBoxClass").click(function (event) {
       var selectedid = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
       event.preventDefault();
       $.get("/Estimate/GetEpicPropertyDetails", { id: selectedid }, function (result) {
         $(".TimeClass").val(result);
       });
     });
   });
</script>
```

`result.Name` is obviously wrong I just dont know how to call this the right way.

Comment: Tried it. :) Json only worked when I was returning a string. It would not work if I tried returning a list. Why idk. I mean I guess I could make get methods in my controller but I shouldn't have to do that

Comment: you still cant return it directly like you are doing

Comment: was that a question or r u telling me I can't ? :)

Comment: return Epictemplist.SingleOrDefault(); you cant just return it like this you still need to return it as json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tman, I had a similiar issue that Darin helped me with. I needed to add a $.param to my getJSON. Check out this post [MVC ListBox not passing data to Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036773/mvc-listbox-not-passing-data-to-action)

Comment: Yea still didn't work. And realize that you were returning just one value 'Values.Length' in your GetCS(). I can return just one value to. But when I try to return an object or a list it does not want to work IDK why. Thx for reply :)

Answer (score 1):

try changing your method like this

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetEpicPropertyDetails(int id)
{  
  var Epictemplist = epicRepository.Select().Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).SingleOrDefault();
  return Json(Epictemplist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Than from your JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".ListBoxClass").click(function (event) {
    var selectedid = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get("/Estimate/GetEpicPropertyDetails", { id: selectedid }, function (result) {
      $(".TimeClass").val(result.Name);
    }, 'json');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Nope it calls the jsonresult and passes the id in no problem, but anything inside the $.get doesn't seem to be reached at all. I even tried .getJSON as well

Comment: Have you tried specifying the datatype in the get? The default is html if I don't recall wrong (updated answer)

Comment: u mean saying result.Name? Yes..in the jsonresult, if I change Epictemplist to just "HelloWOrld", it'll work..and just result not result.name

Comment: Well I'm assuming that Epictemplist is a class with at least a property named `Name`. You have to adapt my code to your real object obviously. You can use firebug to see what is returned