# Mvc4 having 2 forms in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So i'm building a simple mvc4 application, I have created all base models for the creation of the DB, from these classes I could naturally create basic controllers with their matching views.
Now my problem: I have the basic create actionresult + view and in this view I wanted that the user would be able to select some values from a dropdownlist which would make creation of new objects simpler.
I tried to achieve this with a second form in my view (the first one is the basic create form) now if I want to use these dropdowns (they filter each other(so first the user must specify a continent, then the dropdown of the countries only shows countries from that continent and after he specifies a country the region dropdown gets updated :) )) the submit of the basic view is always automatically called.

so making the dropdowns update themselves isn't the problem :s it's that the form for the create automatically validates when the dropdowns are updated

this is the controller where the dropdowns filter each other

```
//
// GET: /FederationCenter/Create
public ActionResult Create(string searchRegion, string searchCountry, string searchContinent)
{
  var countries = from c in db.Countries select c;
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContinent))
  {
    Continent searchContinentEnumValue = (Continent)Enum.Parse(typeof(Continent), searchContinent);
    countries = from c in db.Countries where ((int)c.Continent).Equals((int)searchContinentEnumValue) select c;
  }

  var regions = from r in db.Regions where r.Country.Name.Equals(searchCountry) select r;

  ViewBag.searchContinent = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SchoolCup.Domain.Continent)));
  ViewBag.searchCountry = new SelectList(countries, "Name", "Name");
  ViewBag.searchRegion = new SelectList(regions, "Name", "Name");
  return View();
}

//
// POST: /FederationCenter/Create

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(NSSF nssf, string searchRegion, string searchCountry, string searchContinent)
{
  var countries = from c in db.Countries select c;
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchContinent))
  {
    Continent searchContinentEnumValue = (Continent)Enum.Parse(typeof(Continent), searchContinent);
    countries = from c in db.Countries where ((int)c.Continent).Equals((int)searchContinentEnumValue) select c;
  }

  var regions = from r in db.Regions where r.Country.Name.Equals(searchCountry) select r;

  ViewBag.searchContinent = new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SchoolCup.Domain.Continent)));
  ViewBag.searchCountry = new SelectList(countries, "Name", "Name");
  ViewBag.searchRegion = new SelectList(regions, "Name", "Name");
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var naam = Request["searchRegion"];
    Region creatie = (from c in db.Regions where c.Name.Equals(naam) select c).SingleOrDefault();
    nssf.ISFId = 1;
    nssf.RegionId = creatie.RegionId;
    db.NSSFs.Add(nssf);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(nssf);
}
```

and this is my view

```
@model SchoolCup.Domain.POCO.NSSF

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create NSSF</h2>
     <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form" }))
        {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.DropDownList("searchContinent", null, "-- All continents --", new { onchange = "sendForm()" }) 
        @Html.DropDownList("searchCountry", null, "-- All countries --", new { onchange = "sendForm()" })
        @Html.DropDownList("searchRegion", null, "-- All regions --", new { onchange = "sendForm()" })
            <>
            <input type="submit" name= value="Search" />    
        }
    </div>   
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>NSSF</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
```

some more inputs

```
   </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "button" })

    </p>
}

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendForm() {
        document.form.submit()
    }
    </script>
}
```

I've been looking for at least a day and I don't know how to solve this

with regards
Alexander

Comment: Your question is not clear but it is almost clear. ;)  I think if you expand this sentence with more information: `now if I want to use these dropdowns (they filter each other) the submit of the basic view is always automatically called.` then your question will become clear to everyone.

Comment: so first the user must specify a continent, then the dropdown of the countries only shows countries from that continent and after he specifies a country the region dropdown gets updated :) sry for the big post :s

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497524/easiest-way-to-create-a-cascade-dropdown-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-c-sharp. The answer uses AJAX to fetch new options as a JSON response then replace the select items.

Comment: making the dropdowns update themselves isn't the problem :s it's that the form for the create automatically validates when the dropdowns are updated

Comment: @AlexanderVanLoock Please add that to your question. It will help others understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about either (1) using JQuery and loading the drop-down with a Partial view returned by your controller or (2) you could have an AJAX call that would return your values as a JSON object mapped from your entity and you can render them in the drop-down. This way your form won't be submitted every time you update a drop-down.

The first solution might look something like this:

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$("#searchContinent").change(function() { 
    $("#searchCountry").load("/YourController/GetCountries", { 'continentId': $(this).val() },
                                        function (response, status, xhr) {
                                            if (status == "error") {
                                                alert("An error occurred while loading the results.");
                                            }
                                        });
});
</script>

@Html.DropDownList("searchContinent", null, "-- All continents --" }) 
<div id="searchCountry">
    <!--the newly created drop-down will be placed here-->
</div>
```

---

**(EDIT)**

For Javascript you might try something like this:

**YOUR CURRENT VIEW**

```
@Html.DropDownList("searchContinent", null, "-- All continents --", new { onchange = "getCountries(this)" }) 
<div id="searchCountry">
<!--the newly created drop-down will be placed here-->
</div>

<script> 
function getCountries(input){
    var selectedValue = input.options[input.selectedIndex].value;
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", "YourController/GetCountries?continentId="+selectedValue, false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
    document.getElementById("searchCountry").innerHTML=serverResponse ;
}
</script>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** This I have never tried so if it's wrong don't hesitate to let me know and correct it if necessary

**(END EDIT)**

---

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult GetCountries(string continentId)
    {
        /*Get your countries with your continentId and return a Partial View with a list of 
          countries as your model*/


        return PartialView(countryList);
    }
```

**GetCountries VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<SchoolCup.Domain.Country>

@Html.DropDownListFor( 0, Model)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery :s so I don't realy know how to implement this solution

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library. It's really easy. What you have to do is include the JQUERY libraries and add the bit of code I provided to your view in a <script> tag. What that is doing is that it is associating that function to your element's "onchange" event and when it is fired it will execute. But you can also do this with pure Javascript if that is easier. I can translate the JQUery into pure Javascript and edit my response.

Comment: if that wouldn't be to much trouble you would really help me out :D

Comment: I think I got a little ahead of myself there :) I haven't developed AJAX calls in pure Javascript but I'll try and find out how unless someone else helps us out here. However I must emphasize that it is truly truly easy to do with [JQUERY](http://jquery.com/download/) and you don't have to add much more to your project, trust me. If you decide to use it, don't hesitate to ask me if you get stuck on something.

Comment: I'll try and give it a shot ;)

Comment: I've edited the response with some Javascript. Not sure it will work but give it a try and see.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help :) i'm going to sleep now because it's 2.30 am :p it didn't get it to work yet but I'll keep you posted tomorrow , tx again

Comment: One thing that might give you trouble is the YourController/GetCountries URL. You might have to prepend a "/" or "../" depending on where your script is defined. One way of knowing if your controller call is actually working is calling the URL directly from your browser.

Comment: i fixed it with JQuery and partial views wich fill the dropdowns :)