# how to give default value for multiple dropdown(Country and City)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i try to make drop down list for city and country..
when dropdown Country was select, drop down country show city in country..

this my code

Controller

```
        public ActionResult Customer()
        {
            List<Country> country = _CustomerService.GetCountryForDropDown();
            CustomerViewModel model = CustomerBuilder.BuildCountries(country);
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCityByCountry(int CountryID)
        {
            List<City> city = _CustomerService.GetCityForDropDown();
            CustomerViewModel model = CustomerBuilder.BuildCities(city);

            List<DDCity> getCityFromCountry = new List<DDCity>();
            getCityFromCountry = model.DDCityModel.Where(r => r.CountryID == CountryID).ToList();
            SelectList CityinCountry = new SelectList(getCityFromCountry, "CityID", "CityName", 0);
            return Json(CityinCountry);
        }
```

My viewModel and Function to submit value from Dropdown to ViewModel

```
public class DDCountry
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DDCity
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public List<CustomerItem> ListCustomer { get; set; }
        public CustemerRequest Request { get; set; }
        public EditCustomer EditCustomer { get; set; }
        public List<DDCountry> DDCountryModel { get; set; }
        public List<DDCity> DDCityModel { get; set; }
        public SelectList GetCity { get; set; }

    }

 public static CustomerViewModel BuildCities (List<City> city)
        {
            CustomerViewModel model = new CustomerViewModel();
            model.DDCityModel = new List<DDCity>();

            foreach (var cities in city)
            {
                DDCity ct = new DDCity
                {
                    CityID = cities.CityID,
                    CityName = cities.CityName,
                    CountryID = cities.CountryID
                };
                model.DDCityModel.Add(ct);
            }
            return model;
        }

        public static CustomerViewModel BuildCountries(List<Country> country)
        {
            CustomerViewModel model = new CustomerViewModel();
            model.DDCountryModel = new List<DDCountry>();

            foreach (var countries in country)
            {
                DDCountry ct = new DDCountry
                {
                    CountryID = countries.CountryID,
                    CountryName = countries.CountryName
                };
                model.DDCountryModel.Add(ct);
            }
            return model;
        }
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCity(_CountryID) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $('#ddlCity').html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/MasterDataCustomer/GetCityByCountry/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { CountryID: _CountryID },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select City</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $('#ddlCity').html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("", ""))
                {                    
                    @Html.Label("Country - City")
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DDCountryModel, new SelectList(Model.DDCountryModel, "CountryID", "CountryName"), new { @id = "ddlstate", @style = "width:100px;margin-left:38px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })
                    <select id="ddlCity" name="ddlCity" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 5px;"></select>
                }
```

i try to give default value from drop down using session, but, its not work.
i give default value from my controller, but, just in my DropDown for country.
how can i give default value from country and city, when in Country, default value is "Italia", and the default value is "Rome", and DropDown City can show all City in "Italia"

Comment: This is not a good way of creating cascading drop-down lists. Here you can find a better solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497524/easiest-way-to-create-a-cascade-dropdown-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can have a field in the country called defaultCityId .And also a property to the City IsSelected. Then when you are building the city list just set the specific default city IsSelected property to true.
And then in the client side,

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
  markup += "<option selected="+data[x].IsSelected? "Selected":""+ " value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you can set `default value` for your `dropdownlist`

**Model**

```
 public class CustomerModel
    {

    public int CustomerNameId { get; set; }

    public string customerIdName { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CustomerNameIdList { get; set; }
 }
```

**Controller**

```
 model.CustomerNameIdList.Insert(0, (new CustomerModel { CustomerNameId = 0, customerIdName = " No Organization Size" }));
```