# How to work with Nested Dropdown list in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Have a Dynamic Dropdown list populated with Data from Database like

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID,
                               (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList,
                               "-- Choose a Project --", 
                               new { @class = "ddlProjectvalue" })
}
```

I have populated data by writing method like

```
public SelectList getProjects()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> projectslist = (from proj in res.PROJECTs 
                                                where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" 
                                                select proj
                                               ).AsEnumerable()
                                                .Select(projt => new SelectListItem() 
                                                { 
                                                    Text = projt.NAME, 
                                                    Value = projt.ID.ToString() 
                                                });

    return new SelectList(projectslist, "Value", "Text", PROJ_ID);
}
```

and I have called in contoller and stored in ViewBag.Projects like

```
ViewBag.ProjectList = timesheetModel.getProjects();
// Ex: Contain list like item1,item2,item3
```

Now I want in Dynamic Dropdown list like
if we select a item from  First Dropdowlist should not show in Second Dropdown list(Ex. if we selected item1, should not show item1 in second Dropdown list), and next in third dropdown list should not show in both.
How can I do that in Asp.net MVC? Please help me, i am not getting any ideas.

///Edited

I Have Tried with Script like

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ddlProjectvalue').change(function () {

            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue != '') {
                debugger;
               @* location.href = '@Url.Action("GetDDLData", "Employer")?selectedValue=' + selectedValue;*@
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("/Employer/GetDDLData")', { selectedValue: selectedValue }, function (jsondata) {
                    var dllSecond = $('.ddlProjectvalue');
                    dllSecond.empty();
                    alert(selectedValue);
                    $.each(jsondata, function (index, data) {

                        dllSecond.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: data.value,
                            text: data.text
                        }));
                    });
                });
            }

        });
    });
  </script>
```

and I Have added Json Result in Employer Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetDDLData(string selectedValue)
    {
        int projectid = Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue);

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> projectslist = (from proj in db.PROJECTs where proj.IS_DELETED == "N" && proj.ID != projectid select proj).AsEnumerable().Select(projt => new SelectListItem() { Text = projt.NAME, Value = projt.ID.ToString() });
        var result= new SelectList(projectslist, "Value", "Text", tm.PROJ_ID);
        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Still Not Getting it, where do am Wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is cascading dropdownlist.

What you can do is on the first dropdownlist select call ajax and use your logic to filter selection of second dropdownlist.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID,
                               (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList,
                               "-- Choose a Project --", 
                               new { @id = "ddlProjectvalue" })
```

Filter below dropdown based on first selection.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GetTimeSheetDetails[i].PROJ_ID,
                               (SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectList,
                               "-- Choose a Project --", 
                               new { @id = "ddlSecond" })


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ddlProjectvalue').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedValue != null && selectedValue != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("/YourController/FilterSecondDDL")', { selectedValue: selectedValue }, function (jsondata) {
                var dllSecond = $('#ddlSecond');
                dllSecond.empty();
                $.each(jsondata, function (index, data) {
                    dllSecond.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: data.value,
                        text: data.text
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult FilterSecondDDL(string selectedValue)
{
    //filter and return json.    
    return Json();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this case is for two dropdown lists,I have multiple dropdown lists with same id, What to do?@

Comment: I have just shown you example. You should do same process as for second. It's mean, on the second dll select again call ajax and return  filtured json string which would be for third dll.

Comment: Ya. But problem is "Id" of ddl changes every row, how can i get that, i have class id, but not working..

Comment: what's problem in that. Use common class name for all dll and find selected id on change event of that. Here is the example how you can do that. http://jsfiddle.net/369tU/

Comment: Thanks, it is getting, but how to filter and bind to dynamic ddls?

Comment: You have already data for dll (IEnumerable<SelectListItem> projectslist). After ajax call, in controller FilterSecondDDL(string selectedValue), filter projectslist based on selected value you get and return it as json result. Use this link for return json correctly for ddl. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497524/easiest-way-to-create-a-cascade-dropdown-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-c-sharp

Comment: Still not getting it, i am geting confused that how it works? I have edited my question which was i have tried with your clue, please check  it and help me please.