# Connection between Three Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Three dropdownlist (one for year, month and day) should have a connection between based on this code `List<date> myDate = new List<date>();`.

For instance if you select `2012`, then you select `February`, it should display day `1 to 29`, not to `28`.

Another example is when you select `January`, it shows `1 to 31`.

If you select `2011`, then you select `Feb`, it should display `1 to 28`

Question:
How should I create it in ASP.net mvc?

Another info:

- If posssible, the request is to retrieve the data from cshtml.
- Can't use datepicker because end users' browser are old.

Comment: Why not just use a datepicker? But you will need javascript/jquery to handle this.

Comment: use jquery datepicker instead of list controls..

Comment: They call it **cascading dropdown**. Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497524/easiest-way-to-create-a-cascade-dropdown-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-c-sharp