# How to change Dynamic Dropdown items in mvc 4(It not a casecaddind dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have 3 dropdown in my view page. @HTML.Dropdownlistfor().My dropdown items are in database.

```
The dropdown items are :

     id    name
      0    SELECT
      1      A
      2      B
      3      C
```

My requirements are:

1)When my 1st dropdown selected value is( A ),Then 2nd and 3rd    dropdown only show (SELECT , B ,C).
 2)Now my 1st dropdown change    Selected Value( A ) into (SELECT),Then 2nd dropdown show( (SELECT,A ,    B ,C).

How to implement this concept .

Comment: You need to use Ajax for this. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497524/easiest-way-to-create-a-cascade-dropdown-in-asp-net-mvc-3-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Handle the `.change()` event of the first dropdown. Depending on its value, show or hide the relevant `<option>` elements in the other dropdowns.

Comment: HI Stephan,Please  post a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, just bind a `change` event on first dropdown and check the condition for if the value is not select then hide that specific item from the second dropdown else show all the hidden options from the second dropdown.

```js
$('#dd1').change(function() { // change event bound on first dropdown
  var index = $(this).find(':selected').index(); // get the index here
  if (this.value !== 'select') { // check if the value is not 'select'
    $('#dd2').find('option:hidden').show();
    $('#dd2').find('option:eq('+index+')').hide();
    // get the selected option index and hide it.
  } else {
    $('#dd2').find('option:hidden').show();
    // if the value is select then show the hidden option.
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='dd1'>
  <option>select</option>
  <option value='A'>A</option>
  <option value='B'>B</option>
  <option value='C'>C</option>
</select>
<select id='dd2'>
  <option>select</option>
  <option value='foo'>Foo</option>
  <option value='bar'>Bar</option>
  <option value='baz'>Baz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hai jai,Nice demo ,but one problem,My requirement are each dropdown selected value is unique

Comment: Okay! i get it now so you can do get the index of the option then you can hide it with that index. wait i will update it.

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto check updated.

Comment: Problems on 3 times continiously select and change selected value in 1st dropdown,the 2nd dropdown showed only SELECT option

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto So now let me guess the requirement is : if one is hidden after selection then on next change hidden will be shown and currently selected element will be hidden. right.

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto put this line before hiding: `$('#dd2').find('option:hidden').show();` see the updated one.

Comment: ,yes jai,Your guess is right

Comment: just updated see if that solves your issue.

Comment: ,Almost right,just 2 correction only left. 1)When 2nd dropwn selected value is ( C ),the 1st dropdown does't show the (C),but it showing.2)Your 2nd  dropdown show index number, Pls change it,Please Update your code

Comment: Your request to change the (2nd) correction is just for demo pupose but still i have changed it so that you can understand that `index` is different than `value`. Now Correction (1st) i don't get it. Is it something like dependent on each other. if change first one then affect secon one and if second one is having change event then first one is affected.

Comment: Thanku @jai,Please correct correction (1st),

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto That seems to be a small edit would you mind to do it yourself, this will help you understanding the basics of it. when you fail or get stuck then comeback and ask for it, i definitely answer for that. so what you asked is already been answered actually.

Comment: ,Ok jai,Thanku so much